# Web Form with next button

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

So, I am creating a simple form:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="FirstName">First Name <span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="LastName">Last Name <span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" />
  </td>
</tr>
<input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="catwebformbutton" />
```

What I would like it to do is when the user click submit, it will take them to another page where those details will be confirmed, or simply shown to them. any ideas? or sample codes?

Comment: You need to wrap it in a form tag. See the guide below for more details. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: Learn about forms, and for the love of god please don't use tables for layout purposes.

Comment: @Typhomism, anti-table dogma does not help answer the question. At best, it is distracting. This community is constructive. Please keep it that way.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon in this community, so I'll just comment a link that may be a good starting place for you to learn. I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

where the form ? I cant see any form in your code !

try create 2 php files

index.php file

```
<form action="next_page.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="FirstName">First Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="LastName">Last Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
        <input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="catwebformbutton"  />
</form>
```

next_page.php file

```
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName  = $_POST['LastName'];

echo "first Name : ".$FirstName."<br>";
echo "last Name : ".$LastName."<br>";
```

---

you want to use form method post  and action form to do action in other page ,
and post data in another page using $_POST[]

Good references may be helpful to learn these things :

- about form method ->
  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp
- about form action ->
  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp
- about $_POST in php ->
  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: great thanks, could you please tell me where I would put the code for this info to be sent to my email, so user click submit, this gets mailed to me and takes the user to next_page.php

Comment: after post information in next_page.php

$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName  = $_POST['LastName'];

send the information using mail() function > 
then echo information to user